# Connecting JSON AFnetworking 2.0

Tags: php, ios, json, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I am developing iOS application , I am having problem in receiving data from the client to server using AFnetworking 2.0. Json, Following is my code for using post method on iOS, Please help !

I need server side code (php), How can I obtain the data

**Post on iOS**

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
NSDictionary *params = @ {@"user" :@"Akhtar", @"pwd" :@"123" };
[manager POST:@"URl" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
{
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    [self ResponseHandlingWithResponseData:responseObject WithTag:tag];
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
{
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    [self errorResponseHandlingWithResponseDict:error.userInfo WithTag:tag];
}];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this piece of code

```
<?php
header('Content-type: application/json');

$isPostRequest = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST';

if ($isPostRequest)
{
    $jsonString = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $jsonArray = json_decode($jsonString, true);

    $response = ["status" => "ok"];

    echo json_encode($jsonArray);

}


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The PHP code will be:

```
$var = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
echo '{}';
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your code but its not working with me, Here is the error log   2014-09-01 11:03:20.127 MEMC[875:60b] Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0xa288860 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}

Comment: Sorry, The Error is because iOS expecting json response. I edited the answer